# AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'client'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am a new user of discord.py, and i'm facing an issue with a simple code :

```py
from dotenv import load_dotenv

import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import os

load_dotenv()


class Bothoven:
    def __init__(self):
        self.version = 0.1
        self.client = discord.Client()
        self.bot = Bot(command_prefix='$')

        @self.bot.event
        async def on_ready():
            print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(self.bot))

        @self.bot.command()
        async def test(ctx):
            print(ctx)
            await ctx.send("oui maitre")

        self.bot.run(os.getenv("BOT_TOKEN"))
```

When I run it, everything seems good, the bot prints :

```
We have logged in as Bothoven#9179
```

But when I type something in the guild, it rises an exception :

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PROJETS\Bothoven\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\PROJETS\Bothoven\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 942, in on_message
    await self.process_commands(message)
  File "D:\PROJETS\Bothoven\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 935, in process_commands
    if message.author.client:
AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'client'
```

I understand the error, and I agree that author has no attribute client, but this statement is in bot.py, a library file.

Have you some idea of how to proceed ?

I'm runing python3.8 and discord.py 1.6

**EDIT** :

Despite pip was telling me all packages were up to date, deleting my venv and rebuilding it resolved my issue.

Comment: Try updating the library? `pip install --upgrade discord.py`

Comment: it's all already updated or satisfied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your Cog setup:

- You have to use `commands.Cog.listener()` to exploit events
- To create commands, use the `commands.command()` decorator
- Your `self.bot` definition is wrong and you don't need `self.client`

Here how you would setup your cog correctly:

```py
from os import environ
from discord.ext import commands 

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')

class Bothoven(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready():
        print('Logged in as {0.user}'.format(self.bot))

    @commands.command()
    async def test(ctx):
        print(ctx)
        await ctx.send("Oui maître")

bot.add_cog(Bothoven(bot))
bot.run(environ["BOT_TOKEN"])
```

You can find more about cogs [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/cogs.html#ext-commands-cogs).

**EDIT :** Turns out it was a venv issue, re-building it solved the problem.

Comment: I suppose that you forgot make Beethoven a child of commands.Cog ? 
I assume that your solution is way prettier, but it goes to the same error in on_message.

Comment: There's no `on_message` function in your code ^^ I can't help you in this case

Comment: The stack trace is present in the original message, and as you can see, the exception is not rised directly in my code, but in bot.py, in the method process_command, which is called by on_message, whick is naturally called every time i post on the guild.

Comment: Could you add me on discord (Mr_Spaar#1234) ? I'll be able to help you more (and in french).